# Data is not fetched by dataflow for History object in analytics after sandbox refresh?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

Dataset is not fetching records from history object of one the custom object in my sandbox although there are more than 130 records in backend.Node does not contain any custom filter condition.This is happening only after sandbox refresh earlier i could fetch data from history object.Could anyone please help ??

Comment: Is your sandbox full copy sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the replication again for that History object solved the issue.